# Can not set ORACLE_BASE with oraenv command after install in CENTOS 7 server

Tags: oracle-12c, centos-7

Im trying to install Oracle DB version 12.1.0.2.0-1 in my customer server, my installer file name is oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm. After run this file with `sudo rpm -i oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm` I can not see any message and ORACLE_BASE or ORACLE_HOME folder is missing too. I tried some steps:

1. export ORACLE_BASE=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
2. run oraenv, it asks ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME but when enter I get error

   **ORACLE_BASE environment variable is not being set since this
   information is not available for the current user ID ABC.
   You can set ORACLE_BASE manually if it is required.
   Resetting ORACLE_BASE to its previous value or ORACLE_HOME
   The Oracle base has been set to /home/oracle**
3. Try to reinstall rpm file but nothing good happen.

With missing home folder from installer I can not set many things, I can not do like desktop enviroment with user interface. Please help me.

Comment: This is some huge mess. What do you actually want to do? Install DB software? Then why did you try installing the Instant Client?

Comment: @BalazsPapp I need to connect to oracle database, I dont know where to start so I try what I can. I think install Instant Client can help me do this.

Comment: I want to create listener

Comment: Im trying to use Universal Installer but it requires X Server

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you see that message, it is an error in the oratab. “. oraenv” uses what it finds in your oratab to setup the environment.

If when you run ". oraenv" and it asks you for all the information, (ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID), that usually means you need to add an entry to the oratab.

If you have any mistakes in the oratab, it will not set the environment variables properly and complain about the ORACLE_BASE.

On a Linux box you can usually find the oratab in /etc. On a Sun server the oratab is in “/var/opt/oracle“.  Make yourself a backup and edit or add the line for your database instance.

It should look something like:
OVAPROD01:/u01/app/odaorahome/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_7:N

This entry will produce the error you describe:
OVAPROD01:u01/app/odaorahome/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_7:N